# What can I do with this bottleneck

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop, optimization, graph-algorithm

I have just found a way to optimize the algorithm of my code from 50 to 15 minutes, but it takes 14 minutes on this part. It will be a part of a bigger modelisation system so I can't afford to make it run to long. Since I have to compare between all the value of my vector which have around 100,000 values(10 billion comparison), I was wondering if there was a way to optimize the code.

```
struct Coor 
{ 
    double x1; double y1; //Coordinate of Node 1
    double x2; double y2; //Coordinate of Node 2
    std::vector<int> C1; //Index of the edges connected to Node 1
    std::vector<int> C2; //Index of the edges connected to Node 2
};

std::vector<Coor> Connection_S(std::vector<Coor> Nodes)
{
    N = Nodes.size();

    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        {
            if (i == j)
            { 
                continue; 
            }
            if ( ( Nodes[i].x1 == Nodes[j].x1 && Nodes[i].y1 == Nodes[j].y1 ) ||
                 ( Nodes[i].x1 == Nodes[j].x2 && Nodes[i].y1 == Nodes[j].y2 ) )
            {
                Nodes[i].C1.push_back(j);
            }
            if ( ( Nodes[i].x2 == Nodes[j].x1 && Nodes[i].y2 == Nodes[j].y1 ) ||
                 ( Nodes[i].x2 == Nodes[j].x2 && Nodes[i].y2 == Nodes[j].y2 ) )
            {
                Nodes[i].C2.push_back(j);
            }
        }
    }
    return Nodes;
}
```

I am still relatively new to C++ so I am not used to all possibility the language can offer and the distinction that make a function faster than another.

Comment: You could cut this in half *immediately* by not comparing A:B if you've already compared B:A. Note you go through the entire space in a geometric fashion, O(N^2), the whole square, when all you need to do is compute one half. Second loop can be `j < i` which also strips off `i == j` as a condition.

Comment: You could also index your entries on `x1` and `x2` into a `std::map`, then only compare entries sharing the same bucket. Your algorithm here is brutally inefficient. It's also worth noting that your compiler may or may not inline code that removes the duplicated `Noeuds[i]` type calls. Each of those lookups might be painful. Instead capture each as a variable and reference those or check that your compiler optimization flags are set correctly.

Comment: @tadman good advice, in my case, I had to set the second the second loop like this to work `for (j=(i+1);j<N;++j)`. I tried with a smaller vector for now but I got 5.78 seconds instead of 10,23.

Comment: That's the other half of the square, but the same principle. Either half should work.

Comment: @tadman: Could you post this information in an _answer_? Thanks.

Comment: Have you run a profiler on this?  until you know whether the time is going in the comparison, the vector push_back or somewhere else you are not going to get very far.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Didn't think there was enough there for a full answer, just some hints.

Comment: @tadman: Ok well this is a Q&A not a chatroom :) Thanks

Comment: Added a sample code that uses sorting to my answer. It reduces the time for processing 100000 elements from 55 seconds to 3 seconds.

Comment: Would it be reasonable to rename the question to something like "How to build a graph from coordinates of edge endpoints?"?

Answer (score 2):

The function `Connection_S_optimized` in sample code below can process an array of 100000 Coor's in 3 seconds while the original code does it in 55 seconds.

The main idea of the code below is that endpoints are sorted and put in a multimap. Both node 1 coordinates and node 2 coordinates are put in the same map, noting which enpoint it was.

Then with a single pass through the groups of endpoints that are the same we fill the arrays C1 and C2 of each Coor.

Please note that the optimized version works differently than the original on vectors for which x1,y1 ir the same point as x2,y2.

As was pointed out by someone already, comparing doubles for equality can be dangerous, therefore, you can adjust the function `is_same_coordinate` to compare approximately.

This code SEEMS to work but use it at your own risk, or course.

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

struct Coor
{
    double x1; double y1; //Coordinate of Node 1
    double x2; double y2; //Coordinate of Node 2
    std::vector<int> C1; //Index of the edge connected to Node 1
    std::vector<int> C2; //Index of the edge connected to Node 2
};

bool is_same_coordinate(std::pair<double, double> e1, std::pair<double, double> e2)
{
    return (e1.first == e2.first) && (e1.second == e2.second);
}

std::vector<Coor> Connection_S(std::vector<Coor> Noeuds)
{
    size_t N = Noeuds.size();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        {
            if (i == j)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if ((Noeuds[i].x1 == Noeuds[j].x1 && Noeuds[i].y1 == Noeuds[j].y1) || (Noeuds[i].x1 == Noeuds[j].x2 && Noeuds[i].y1 == Noeuds[j].y2))
            {
                Noeuds[i].C1.push_back(j);
            }
            if ((Noeuds[i].x2 == Noeuds[j].x1 && Noeuds[i].y2 == Noeuds[j].y1) || (Noeuds[i].x2 == Noeuds[j].x2 && Noeuds[i].y2 == Noeuds[j].y2))
            {
                Noeuds[i].C2.push_back(j);
            }
        }
    }
    return Noeuds;
}


void Connection_S_optimized(std::vector<Coor>& Noeuds)
{
    // A map of an endpoint coordinates to the information about this enpoint <is it the Node 1 (x1, y1), index in Noeuds>
    std::multimap<std::pair<double, double>, std::pair<bool, size_t>> node_index;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < Noeuds.size(); i++)
    {
        Coor& c = Noeuds[i];
        node_index.insert(std::make_pair(std::pair<double, double>(c.x1, c.y1), std::pair<bool, size_t>(true, i)));
        node_index.insert(std::make_pair(std::pair<double, double>(c.x2, c.y2), std::pair<bool, size_t>(false, i)));
    }
    auto s_representative_it = node_index.begin();
    for (auto s_it = node_index.begin();; s_it++)
    {
        if (s_it == node_index.end() || !is_same_coordinate(s_representative_it->first, s_it->first))
        {
            auto start = s_representative_it;
            auto end = s_it;
            auto current = s_representative_it;
            while (current != end)
            {
                bool is_node_1 = current->second.first;
                Coor& current_coor = Noeuds[current->second.second];
                auto it = start;
                while (it != end)
                {
                    if (it != current)
                    {
                        if (is_node_1)
                        {
                            current_coor.C1.push_back(it->second.second);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            current_coor.C2.push_back(it->second.second);
                        }
                    }
                    it++;
                }
                current++;
            }
            if (s_it == node_index.end())
            {
                break;
            }
            s_representative_it = s_it;
        }
    }
}

const size_t NUM_COORS = 100000;

void generate_sample_set(std::vector<Coor>& Noeuds)
{
    Coor c;
    size_t degenerated = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_COORS + degenerated; i++)
    {
        c.x1 = i % 23;
        c.x2 = i % 13;
        c.y1 = i % 5;
        c.y2 = i % 17;
        if (is_same_coordinate(std::make_pair(c.x1, c.y1), std::make_pair(c.x2, c.y2)))
        {
            degenerated++;
            continue;
        }
        Noeuds.push_back(Coor(c));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<Coor> Noeuds_input;

    generate_sample_set(Noeuds_input);

    std::vector<Coor> Noeuds_original = Noeuds_input;
    std::vector<Coor> Noeuds_optimized = Noeuds_input;

    double time_original = clock();
    Noeuds_original = Connection_S(Noeuds_original);
    time_original = (clock() - time_original) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    double time_optimized = clock();
    Connection_S_optimized(Noeuds_optimized);
    time_optimized = (clock() - time_optimized) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < std::min(Noeuds_input.size(), 100u); i++)
    {
        std::cout << i << ": " << Noeuds_original[i].C1.size() << "," << Noeuds_original[i].C2.size()
            << " vs " << Noeuds_optimized[i].C1.size() << "," << Noeuds_optimized[i].C2.size() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Processing time for " << NUM_COORS << " items (in seconds):" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  original: " << time_original << std::endl;
    std::cout << " optimized: " << time_optimized << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One additional optimization to save memory would be to not have C1 and C2 arrays for each vector but to introduce new type of objects -- vertices -- that would be pointed to by each Coor and that would, in turn, point to Coors that start or end there. Currently, depending on how many Coors meet in one point, there is a lot of redundant information stored in the C1 and C2 arrays.

Answer (score 2):

### Compiler Optimization Settings

First print out the assembly language listing.
Next, set the optimization levels on High for Speed; recompile.
Compare optimized assembly to non-optimized assembly.

### Preloading variables

You may be able to get some savings by *preloading* the values you are comparing. *(Note:  The compiler may do this already; check your local assembly language for the truth.)*
Example:

```
const double ni_x1(Nodes[i].x1);
const double ni_x2(Nodes[i].x2);
const double nj_y1(Nodes[i].y1);
const double nj_y2(Nodes[i].y2);

if (((ni_x1 == nj_x1) && (ni_y1 == nj_y1))
// ...
```

The optimization technique here is to allow the processor to prefetch the data into its data cache.

### Reducing branch instructions

Branch instructions take more time for the processor to execute than data instructions.  So, if possible, eliminate them.
*(Some processors have enough cache to load a loop into instruction cache without having to reload.  In any case, the processor still has some extra logic to perform, which takes more time than processing a data instruction.)*

You could use some Boolean algebra.  Again, review the assembly language to see if you gained any speed.
Example:

```
bool is_equal = false;
is_equal = (ni_x1 == nj_x1);
is_equal = is_equal && (ni_y1 == nj_y1);
```

The above may allow the compiler to generate conditional assembly instructions, if your processor has that.  Hopefully, the compiler can generate continuous data instructions.

### Fixed Point arithmetic

Another option is to use fixed point arithmetic.  This would allow integral arithmetic operations, which are usually faster than floating point operations.

For example, given volumes in Liters, there is a possiblity to have 3.141 liters.  If the value is represented as *milliliters*, the value would be integral: 3141.

Advantages:  better accuracy and equality works.  For example, with a 32-bit processor, you could have 32 bits of "mantissa", whereas a floating point may only have 24 bits of "mantissa" because some bits are reserved for sign and exponent.

Comment: These are good suggestions but they go only so far. You cannot get a bubble sort outperform heapsort however you optimize, as the data amount increases.

Answer (score 1):

you can resize the Noeuds[i] vectors before looping. This will improve memory management and performance. **Pass the struct  Noeuds by reference. Now it is copying it. This will take time**.

Change `Connection_S(std::vector<Coor> Noeuds)`
to `Connection_S(std::vector<Coor> &Noeuds)`
When you pass by reference you don't have to return it.
The original will be updated directly.

On a side note: Comparing doubles by == doesn't give you always same result. So it is dangerous.

Comment: When I tried to pass my vector by reference, it took one more minute to complete. Maybe I did it wrong `std::vector<Coor> Connection_B(std::vector<Coor> &Noeuds)`?

Comment: You don't need to return the same again. you can change the return to void.  void Connection_B(std::vector<Coor> &Noeuds)

Comment: It's more likely to be moved than copied.

Answer (score 1):

there are a few things you can do:

1. sort the whole vector beforehand This operation is O(nlogn) compared to that you are doing now, which is O(N*N). Than you can find a more efficient way of populating C1/C2.
2. You can also try do more than one comparison at a time; j will increase by 2, 4 ..etc. This will improve your cache locality and should generate more compact code.

Answer (score 0):

Side note: the plural of "Node" is "Nodes" ;-)

`std::vector` internally uses dynamically-allocated arrays, which means that the `push_back` operation, as explained [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), may need to reallocate memory and then *copy all the data already in the vector*. Depending on the size of your vector, this may be a fairly expensive operation.

Instead, consider using some other containers. `std::list` is fairly efficient at adding elements at the end, but doesn't support random access. Alternatively, you may want to use a `std::deque`, which doesn't guarantee that all elements are in contiguous storage (like a vector does), but still allows fairly efficient random access.

Comment: I think there used to be `std::vector.reserve()` or something that might come in handy (but I didn't do a lot of C++ in the past 10 years, so I might be wrong).

Comment: [indeed](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/). However, the problem with that is that you would need to know beforehand what the size of your vector is going to be. It is unlikely you'll know that, and when you're wrong, you're back at having to move memory around. `std::list` and `std::deque` don't move things around, so the problem just doesn't exist.

Comment: That's a good advice, but in my case it is highly improbable that I will have more than 3 values to push_back, so I don't think it will make any difference.